# Merge [python-flet] and [flet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tags [python-flet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-flet) and [flet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flet) appear to refer to exactly the same framework. I would suggest merging the two tags, and have the former tag (that includes just over 15 questions at the moment) removed, while maintaining the [flet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flet) tag, which seems to be the predominantly used one and likely better fits the framework in question.

Comment: Per the tag descriptions, it's intended that the framework will support other languages in the future. However, the combination of `flet` and a language tag seems perfectly sufficient to me. It's not as if "flet" means something *different* in Python compared to what it will eventually mean in other languages.

Comment: With so few questions, and what looks like reasonable consensus, I think you can just edit the tags yourself.

Comment: @Chris Just remove the tag from  all the questions and tag them with just [flet]. After 24 hours, the original tag [python-flet] should disappear. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination (single dragon master strategy for questions <50)

Comment: Does it make sense to make a synonym? It seems that the tag may reappear, especially if/when more language support rolls out for flet.

Comment: Yep, [done](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flet/synonyms)